# Makefile to build two source code using a single make file

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am trying to build two source code using a single makefile. I want to build Linux-PAM-1.2.0 first then pam_radius-1.4.0. pam_radius-1.4.0 is the outermost directory and Linux-PAM-1.2.0 is the inner directory.

`| pam_radius-1.4.0
  -- Linux-PAM-1.2.0`

Each has its own make file. I need to first compile Linux-PAM-1.2.0 and then i need to compile pam_radius-1.4.0, as i need to provide path of Linux-PAM-1.2.0 for compiling pam_radius-1.4.0.

I have made some modification in pam_radius-1.4.0 makefile. I need to first compile Linux-PAM-1.2.0 and then i need to compile pam_radius-1.4.0, as i need to provide path of Linux-PAM-1.2.0 for compiling pam_radius-1.4.0 makefile. My make file fails. Before doing make i need to create a install directory. Have made changes to pam_radius-1.4.0 Makefile as follows. I enable mkdir `mkdir $(SUBDIR)/install/` in Makefile and do make i get an error. If i disable mkdir i get a message `make: Linux-PAM-1.2.0' is up to date.`. I have already done make clean in  make: `Linux-PAM-1.2.0' is up to date.

My make file is as follows

```
SUBDIR = Linux-PAM-1.2.0
CC = arc-linux-uclibc-gcc
INSTALL_PATH = $(shell pwd)
LINUX_PAM_PATH = $(shell pwd)/$(SUBDIR)/
mkdir $(SUBDIR)/install/

$(SUBDIR):
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_PAM_PATH)
    $(MAKE) -C install
CFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -I $(INSTALL_PATH)/$(LINUX_PAM)/install/include/
LDFLAGS = -L $(INSTALL_PATH)/$(LINUX_PAM)/install/lib/
all:pam_radius_auth.so
pam_radius_auth.o: src/pam_radius_auth.c src/pam_radius_auth.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
md5.o: src/md5.c src/md5.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
pam_radius_auth.so: pam_radius_auth.o md5.o
pam_radius_auth.so: pam_radius_auth.o md5.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -o pam_radius_auth.so
```

can you please let me know what i am doing wrong here. If i un-comment mkdir i get an error and if i comment then it say make: `Linux-PAM-1.2.0' is up to date.

Comment: Try moving 'mkdir $(SUBDIR)/install/' line  after '$(SUBDIR):'

Comment: tired it out still same issue

Comment: You don't build source code (a C or C++ code which is somehow generated is not source code!). You build programs from their source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Makefile should look like:

```
SUBDIR = Linux-PAM-1.2.0
CC = arc-linux-uclibc-gcc
INSTALL_PATH = $(shell pwd)
LINUX_PAM_PATH = $(shell pwd)/$(SUBDIR)/

CFLAGS = -Wall -fPIC -I $(INSTALL_PATH)/$(LINUX_PAM)/install/include/
LDFLAGS = -L $(INSTALL_PATH)/$(LINUX_PAM)/install/lib/

all: pam_radius_auth.so
    mkdir -p $(SUBDIR)/install/
    $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_PAM_PATH)
    $(MAKE) -C install

pam_radius_auth.so: pam_radius_auth.o md5.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -shared pam_radius_auth.o md5.o -lpam -o pam_radius_auth.so

pam_radius_auth.o: src/pam_radius_auth.c src/pam_radius_auth.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

md5.o: src/md5.c src/md5.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the `all`recipe above all other recipes. It's just convention to call it `all` -- the default target in a Makefile is always the first target.
2. Make `all` depend on the result of your subdir rule. One common trick is to use a `stamp file`, eg.

   ```
   all: pam_radius_auth.so $(SUBDIR)/install/stamp

   $(SUBDIR)/install/stamp:
           mkdir -p $(SUBDIR)/install/
           $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_PAM_PATH)
           $(MAKE) -C $(LINUX_PAM_PATH) install
           touch $(SUBDIR)/install/stamp
   ```
3. Try to understand how Makefiles work in general. They are NOT scripts. You can't just put a command anywhere .... it's always

   ```
   <target>: <dependencies>
           <commands to build target>
   ```
4. That said, the concept is kind of flawed. Your `$(SUBDIR)/install/stamp` rule would have to depend on ANY input file for that subdirectory in order to make dependencies work and rebuild as needed. Now you can just force it by deleting the stamp file.

Comment: Thanks you. As you told i went through make file and told the changes that you had asked for. After i do a make i get make: `Linux-PAM-1.2.0' is up to date . But i have done make clean already.

Comment: extend the "clean" rule to do something like `rm -f $(SUBDIR)/install/stamp; make -C $(SUBDIR) clean`